# Собственный метод в stream

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Можно ли использовать собственный функциональный интрфейс в stream.
например есть список ArrayList drivers = new ArrayList();

```
Stream stream = drivers.stream();
stream. здесь уже вызвать свой метод не используя стандартные ?

Validator<Driver> validator = driver -> !(driver.getName().length() <= 1);

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Validator<T>  {
    boolean isValid(T obj);
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, какой ещё свой метод?

Comment: реализация @FunctionalInterface
public interface Validator<T>    /////                                                                                                                                              Validator<Driver> validator = driver -> !(driver.getName().length() <= 1);

Comment: что значит вызвать isValid на stream? Опишите что вам нужно более чётче и подробнее. С входными и выходными данными. Может быть вы имеете в виду использовать с `filter`/`allMatch` и подобными, где используется `Predicate<T>` интерфейс? Если да, то чем `Predicate<T>` не устраивает?

Comment: проверить список используя свой валидатор через стрим, если можно , если нельзя а используют только дефолт фильтр тогда понятно.

Comment: Почему вы не можете использовать `allMatch` и передать туда ваш метод (естественно переписав его под требуемый интерфейс)?

Comment: не знаю как это, только начал стримы изучать